# Directing routes to specific components using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Im want to use the following layout as the start screen of my page:

```
-----------------------------
| View 1      | View 2      |
| LinkA LinkB | LinkC LinkD |
|             |             |
-----------------------------
```

When `LinkA or B` are clicked I want the routes to be shown in `View 1`,
and when LinkC or D are clicked I want the routes to be shown in `View 2`.

What I have right now is only a way to send multiple components to the App component to render View1 and View2, I dont know how to make specific routes to actually render inside them:

```
  <Route path="/" component={ App }>
    <IndexRoute components={{
        view1: View1,
        view2: View2
      }} />
  </Route>
```

What I know about react-router makes me think I want something more along the lines:

```
  <Route path="/" component={ App }>
    <Route component={View1} >
      <Route to="linkA" component={View1a}/>
      <Route to="linkB" component={View1b}/>
    <Route />
    <Route component={View2} >
      <Route to="linkC" component={View2a}/>
      <Route to="linkD" component={View2b}/>
    <Route />
  </Route>
```

Now my question is how to make the rendering work as I want and are there any tutorials showing this? 
Maybe im missing some basic stuff since I have not been able to find any examples like this and what I assume to be a basic layout for a page...

Comment: You have to specify paths in your router elements. How else will react-router know which components to populate as children? And I'll say 99% of the time you just send a single component per route.. if you want multiple components, create a parent component that has them both, the send that to your router

Comment: I must be missing some basic understanding since i still can not understand how to specify wich links should be rendered under wich view? Could you give an example?

Comment: If i use this.props.children to render routes for my parent component holding bote views all links will be rendered in the same view???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only concern of a react-router config is to determine which component to populate `this.props.children` with based on the current url. You do not specify which links are displayed in the config.. you do this in the component.

In your question you say you want the start screen to contain two views. Maybe you mean two components? Every URL is responsible for one view.

With a config that looks like:

```
<Route path="/" component={ App }>
  <Route path="view1" component={ View1 }>
    <Route path="a" component={ View1a } />
  <Route>
  <Route path="view2" component={ View2 } />
</Route>
```

When the url is `/`, the `App` component's `this.props.children` will be empty. If you use `IndexRoute` it will use the component specified there.

When the url is `/view1`, the `App` component's `this.props.children` will render the `View1` component. Same thing for `/view2` and `View2`.

When the url is `/view1/a`, the `App` component's `this.props.children` will be `View1`, and `View1`'s `this.props.children` will be `View1a`

So if you want to display different links based on the current view, use different links in your `View1` and `View2` components.

Comment: Best explanation i found. Awsome sumury how router works! I was missing the basics but now i get it. Thanks.